# European road usage statistics per highway

Tags: raster, routing, data

I'm looking for an open data source which features the amount of cars per road per day or per year for Europe(!). I've found several national reports, which are only available as PDF and as such a not really processable. The ones by EuroStat are not really feasible. I would like to process this data into a raster to work with it in my database as part of my routing solution. Any suggestions?

P.S.: If there is already a rasterized solution out there, I would certainly prefer that.

Comment: Use the EuroStat Database? http://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/show.do?dataset=road_tf_veh&lang=en

Comment: Yes I was there already, but I need something which goes down to individual highways. EuroStat doesn't provide this unfortunately

Answer (score 3):

At the moment, I could only easily find data for the UK:

http://data.dft.gov.uk/gb-traffic-matrix/Raw_count_data_major_roads.zip

It's in .csv format so you can manipulate it in Excel or by using other softwares (much easier than pdf's!). It also contains coordinates to immediately import the points into GIS software (tested this successfully with QGIS).

The file contains all major roads in the UK with data recorded in 12-hour intervals over various days for several years. I will continue to see if I can find something more substantial but I suppose you can use this as a start.

Comment: Thanks Joseph that's a good start. UK is pretty awesome on OpenData. Still I have hopes in finding data for more countries. I know it's a pretty big deal I'm asking for.